# What causes packet loss from Debian server to nearest gateway?

Tags: linux, debian, kvm-virtualization, gateway, packetloss

I have a debian Squeeze KVM server hosted with an ISP. The server doesn't have much load (average 0.1) and has sufficient memory, low network traffic, low disk i/o etc etc. It's running standard LAMP setup, with all latest deb packages installed. No unusual software installed.

But when I ping the nearest gateway there is an average of 8% packet loss (cron job doing 100 pings every 10 minutes), sometimes as much as 40-50% packet loss, even though the server load is stable. Pinging the server from outside also gives packet loss.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely answer is that the loss has nothing to do with your server, but rather with the network somewhere between you server's network interface and the gateway. Could be port contention somewhere along the line, could be bad cabling, etc.

Either way, it's not your problem to solve. You should contact the ISP, give them the information you've collected, and ask that they fix the problem.